# error==The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format. When I use AFNetworking to request

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

When I request the network:

```
[Mysevers AFPOSTWithHud:YES andAddressname:@"Common/Currency/Register" parmas:params RequestSuccess:^(id result) {

    if ([result[@"status"] intValue] == 200) {

        [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"注册成功"];

        UIViewController *temp_vc = nil;

        for (UIViewController *vc in self.navigationController.childViewControllers) {

            if ([vc isKindOfClass:[HomeVC class]] ) {

                temp_vc = vc;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (temp_vc == nil) {
            return;
        }

        [self.navigationController popToViewController:temp_vc animated:YES];

    }else {

        [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"注册失败"];
    }

} failBlcok:^{
    SVNoNet;
}];
```

I get the error when I request the network:

> [Mysevers AFPOSTWithHud:andAddressname:parmas:RequestSuccess:failBlcok:]_block_invoke.47][行号:57]error==The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Mysevers code is below:

```
@implementation Mysevers

+ (AFHTTPSessionManager *)sharedHTTPSession{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static AFHTTPSessionManager *requestManager ;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        requestManager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
        requestManager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = 10;
        requestManager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];  // 添加，否则会返回500错
        requestManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript", @"text/html", nil];
    });
    return requestManager;
}


+(void)AFPOSTWithHud:(BOOL)hud andAddressname:(NSString*)addressName parmas:(NSDictionary*)parmas RequestSuccess:(void(^)(id result))success failBlcok:(void(^)(void))failBlcok
{
    if (hud) {
        //[HUD addHUD];

        [SVProgressHUD show];
    }

    AFHTTPSessionManager *requestManager = [Mysevers sharedHTTPSession];
    //requestManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",BASE_URL,addressName];
    DLog(@"%@",urlStr);

    [requestManager POST:urlStr parameters:parmas progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {

    } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        if (hud) {
            //[HUD removeHUD];
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        }
        success(responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

        if (error != nil) {
            DLog(@"error==%@",[error localizedDescription]);
            if (hud) {
                //[HUD removeHUD];
                [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            }
            failBlcok();
        }


        return ;
    }];


}
```

---

Attention, my acceptableContentTypes is below:

```
requestManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript", @"text/html", nil]
```

---

**Update**

I change my sharedHTTPSession to this:

```
+ (AFHTTPSessionManager *)sharedHTTPSession{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static AFHTTPSessionManager *requestManager ;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        requestManager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
        requestManager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = 10;
        AFJSONRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
        [serializer setStringEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        requestManager.requestSerializer=serializer;
        //requestManager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];  // 添加，否则会返回500错
        requestManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript", @"text/html", nil];
    });
    return requestManager;
}
```

Still get this error.

PHPer prints the `$_POST`, its a empty Array.

---

```
(lldb) po result
{
    data = "";
    msg = 2001;
    status = 400;
}
```

The result is PHPer returns to me, the `msg` is he defined, just the `$_POST` is empty.

---

**ATTENTION -2**

In My `AFHTTPSessionManager.m`, I add a line to the request header:

```
#pragma mark - add by me

        [request addValue:API_KEY forHTTPHeaderField:@"PUBLICKEY"];
```

In my `AFHTTPSessionManager.m`:

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTaskWithHTTPMethod:(NSString *)method
                                       URLString:(NSString *)URLString
                                      parameters:(id)parameters
                                  uploadProgress:(nullable void (^)(NSProgress *uploadProgress)) uploadProgress
                                downloadProgress:(nullable void (^)(NSProgress *downloadProgress)) downloadProgress
                                         success:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *, id))success
                                         failure:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *, NSError *))failure
{
    NSError *serializationError = nil;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:method URLString:[[NSURL URLWithString:URLString relativeToURL:self.baseURL] absoluteString] parameters:parameters error:&serializationError];

#pragma mark - add by me

    [request addValue:API_KEY forHTTPHeaderField:@"PUBLICKEY"];

    if (serializationError) {
        if (failure) {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wgnu"
            dispatch_async(self.completionQueue ?: dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                failure(nil, serializationError);
            });
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
        }

        return nil;
    }

    __block NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = nil;
    dataTask = [self dataTaskWithRequest:request
                          uploadProgress:uploadProgress
                        downloadProgress:downloadProgress
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * __unused response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            if (failure) {
                failure(dataTask, error);
            }
        } else {
            if (success) {
                success(dataTask, responseObject);
            }
        }
    }];

    return dataTask;
}
```

---

**Update-3**

I put all the prints information to below:

> 2017-05-06 18:03:31.685086 KYGM[15582:531703] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/luowensheng/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2FACECB7-2E7A-4E8C-8AF5-179ED7344D93/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>   2017-05-06 18:03:31.686106 KYGM[15582:531703] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
>   2017-05-06 18:03:39.568 KYGM[15582:531703] [文件名:/Users/luowensheng/Desktop/company_project/KYGM/KYGM/Utils/LML/LMLUtils/Mysevers.m][函数名:+[Mysevers AFPOSTWithHud:andAddressname:parmas:RequestSuccess:failBlcok:]][行号:47]http://192.168.3.103:8003/Common/Currency/Register

---

**Update-04**

If I use the `postman` to request, I will success.

[image]

I don't know if the form-data is the reason.

Comment: In what wrong format is it?

Comment: @vadian I set the `serializer ` to `utf-8`, still get error.

Comment: `utf8` is not a format.

Comment: @vadian What do you mean? what should I provide to you ?

Comment: The error message states *isn’t in the correct format*. Once again: what (wrong) format is it?

Comment: @vadian I update my post, I accessed the API, but my POST params is empty, you can see , I set my param as a Dictionary to pass, I don'w know why my param did not pass to the API. I don't know if is because I add a `PUBLICKEY` header to that cause the error.

Comment: @vadian See my Update -3, my friend.

Answer (score 0):

I find your postman's param-data type is `form-data`, so I think you should use the AFNetworking's form-submit method:

try below code:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript", @"text/html", nil];

    NSDictionary *params = @{
                             @"UserName":@"admin5",
                             @"Password":@"123456"
                             };


    [manager POST:@"your url" parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {

        NSLog(@"formData=%@", formData);

    } progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {

    } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"responseObject=%@", responseObject);

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"error=%@", error);
    }];
```